# Intercept 404's in wp and redirect to a post based on its custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress

So this is the my issue:

1. I have an 'huge' (more than 1000 pages) non wp website that i've ported to wordpress.
2. It's impossible to match the url's from the old website to the new
   website because page titles and general information architecture
   have changed
3. So in a custom post type that will hold the 'Listings' (listings_cpt) i've stored a custom field named old_website_url.
4. My goal was to intercept 404 requests with the template_redirect  hook because from what i've read it looks like appropriate to intercept a 404 before the template is loaded and an actual header is sent.
5. So hypothetically if someone tries to see a page that doesn't exist but its url is stored in old_website_url  from the listings_cpt posts i could redirect him to the post permalink  that holds this value.

I've did a lot of trial/error approaches with no success.

**Can someone point me in the right direction??**
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well your approach should work. Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a custom 404 page that reads all posts
2. For each post read its old_website_url custom field
3. If the old_website_url custom field of a post matches the current url, the user is redirected to the url of the post.

Have a look at the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page)

Comment: Hi Nadir thank you for your help. I think this wont actually prevent the server 404 header to be sent to the client. 
I need to sent an 301 header along with this logic

Comment: Well you can try to send a custom http location header using the header function. It should override the 404 header